# Contentful - GraphQL query suddenly stopped

Tags: graphql, contentful

With no changes to my project in the slightest, my graphql no longer works
Here is the query

```
...
description {
  content { 
    content {
      value
    }
  }
  description
}
...
```

And here was the error:
Cannot query field “content” on type “ContentfulCollectionDescription”.

I removed the issued query then checked http://localhost:8000/__graphql which is now showing:
[image]

Any idea what’s going on and how to fix?

**UPDATE**

I never did figure out what was going on. Instead of dealing with the issue, I created a new field, and now use that

Comment: Did you update dependencies. I'm assuming you're using Gatsby and has been a breaking change introducing `raw`.

Comment: I don't think I updated anything before it broke, but have done some updates since. I have now noticed that some of my content from contentful isn't being pulled down anymore, either..! (of the same type)